# android compose do not open keyboard when button click with using LocalSoftwareKeyboardController

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to handle the keyboard but there is problem can't find the solution.

when the App opens and click the button, the keyboard doesn't open
but after click the textfield(Definitly can see the keyboard) and close the keyboard,
if i click the button again, keyboard opens.

why did that? why the keyboard isn't opening at first?

```kotlin
            val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
            val keyboard = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
          
                Scaffold(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                   ) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .padding(it)
                    ) {
                       
                        TextField(
                            value = "", onValueChange = {}, modifier = Modifier.align(
                                Alignment.TopCenter
                            )
                        )
                        Button(
                            onClick = {
                                keyboard?.show()
                                focusRequester.captureFocus()
                            },
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                        ) {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Was the TextField still in focus after clicking? It might be because of that hence the keyboard only showing after clicking on the TextField. https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/SoftwareKeyboardController#show()

Comment: @Firate Ah... maybe that is the reason. how can i open keyboard without textfield focusing?

Comment: Well based on the docs, it might not be possible.

Comment: "The software keyboard will never show if there is no composable that will accept text input, such as a TextField when it is focused. You may find it useful to ensure focus when calling this function." from [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/SoftwareKeyboardController#show())